# System settings doesn't display graphic drivers in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, nvidia, graphics, bumblebee

I recently installed Ubuntu 13.04 on an Asus K55VD Ci3 with a 4GB RAM, 500GB HDD and a 2GB NVIDA Geforce610m graphics card. I followed all the steps given on Bumblebee wiki. Yet I am unable to see my graphics card in system settings/properties.

Can Anyone help?

Comment: 13.04 support ends **today** - consider upgrading to 13.10 **now**.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter. I also cannot see my graphic card in system -> Settings -> Properties.

The only thing that it is important is that your driver is activated.